# Sbt does not compile generated java files without setting javacOptions

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a multi-project sbt build file.  One of the projects looks like this:

```
lazy val genFiles = (project in file("genFiles")).
    dependsOn(generator).
    settings(
      sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.taskDyn { ... }.taskValue,
      libraryDependences ++= Seq(...) ++ Seq(...),
      javacOptions += "-nowarn"
    )
```

This generates the java files and compiles both the scala and java files.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to /projects/genFiles/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
```

If I remove setting `javacOptions`, then it only tries to compile the scala file and fails, since the scala files reference the java classes.

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /projects/genFiles/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
```

I am running sbt 1.2.8.

Any idea why I need to set `javacOptions`?

Comment: What does your source generator task return? Maybe you can create a small, minimal reproducer project?!